# How to display different leaflet maps on each tab?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, leaflet, angular8

I am developing an Angular web application, where i have few tabs (tabs are created using material-angular).

On selection of each tab, i want to show a different map. I am using leaflet and leaflet-rastercoords angular plugins to display custom maps.

I am able to display a single map on the first tab, However, when ti try to display maps on other tabs, i get various errors while i try different ways -

Strategies I have tried but didn't work -

1. Separate component for each map
2. Separate map initialization in different functions

Please guide me a suitable way or a useful plugin, that would make my life easy.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say a different map on a different tab, I understand that a different location on each tab. To achieve it, you need to give the different feed(input) to each map(latitude /longitude). Here is an example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-buglpd